# Mongo db not start

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i am new to mongo db. And i do not understand why my monggo db is not starting, and instead it is shutting down.

I have an image below, that shows what is going on at the cmd
[cmd, mongo db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ptas.jpg)

Comment: Did you at least read the log? It says clearly what the problem is.

Comment: Dear @user8898744, welcome to the StackOverflow! This is the site where developers help each other. But there are some rules here both formal and informal. And confirming to the informal ones is often as important as with the formal. And the crucial informal rule is: make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first - and then show us what you've already done. Another rule is that you should not use images for texts (such as code or log). It makes easier for other people to work with the text. Use images only if it is really a picture.

Answer (score 1):

Kill all other mongod instance before starting a new instance. The problem is clearly written in the cmd.

Or try to start mongo on another port using

```
mongod --port 27010 --dbpath c:\data\newDb
```

Also, make sure you have `c:\data\newDb` and `c:\data\db` folders created before starting the server.